# Stylizing chained drop-downs with 'dd-slick' jQuery plugin breaks auto-update of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using `jquery.ddslick.min.js` jQuery plug-in to create stylized drop-down boxes with images for the options.  I also am using `jquery.chained.min.js` to auto-update the data in the second select box based on the value selected in the first drop-down.

My requirements are:

- Stylize drop-down boxes to allow images to be used in the options
- Automatically update the data in the second drop-down box based on the option chosen in the first.
- Trigger an alert displaying the value of the option chosen
- Provide scrolling capability of drop-down boxes

Currently, items are not updated in the second select box when I choose an option in the first.  I also am having trouble triggering the alert upon selecting an option; the scroll functionality also is not working properly.

HTML:

```
<select id="inames">
    <option value="">-slect place-</option>
    <option value="Utilities">Utilities</option>
    <option value="Emergency Services">Emergency Services</option>
    <option value="General">General</option>
</select> 

<select id="ddslicks" >
    <option data-imagesrc="../css/PoiImages/airport.png" class="Utilities" value="airport"></option>
    <option data-imagesrc="../css/PoiImages/ambulance.png" class="Utilities" value="ambulance"></option>
    <option data-imagesrc="../css/PoiImages/atm.png" class="General" value="atm"></option>
    <!-- _  _  etc -->
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#ddslicks").chainedTo("#inames"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); */
```

I also get problems when I add an alert.

```
alert($('#ddslicks').val())
```

Comment: from my code when i select General option from inames drop down then it shows only one image is atm.png in ddslicks drop down box and get value is atm. please help and  i am new and save my days.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your JavaScript?  I'm assuming there is more, since I don't see any alerts in your JavaScript that you posted. Ideally, a fiddle with references to your additional JavaScript files (ddlslick and chained) would be particularly helpful.

Comment: [http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained], `$('#ddslicks').ddslick({
  onSelected: function(data)
  {
   
   displaySelectedData("Callback Function on Dropdown Selection" , data);
  }
 });`

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/thiru/Fx4ER/2/** i.e jquery.ddslick.min.js  this for images drop down box,remain code is html.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to use external files - http://jsfiddle.net/Fx4ER/4/

Comment: Quick question - where is "displaySelectedData" located?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53832/discussion-between-laura-ritchey-and-user3599212)

Comment: project still alive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take this or leave it, but here is an alternative solution.  It doesn't use chained, but I believe it accomplishes the same functionality only using ddslick  (http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/Uw9kL/2/).

The method I used takes in JSON data (you can create it manually or use a web service).  It uses the data feature of ddslick (note that I just used sample data).  Also, note that I only put in data for Utilities and General (so you won't see anything with Emergency Services).

```
var categoryData = [{
    text: "Utilities",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Utilities"
}, {
    text: "Emergency Services",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "Emergency Services"
}, {
    text: "General",
    value: 3,
    selected: false,
    description: "General"
}];

var utilitiesData = [{
    text: "Airport",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Airport",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
}];

var generalData = [{
    text: "Mall",
    value: 11,
    selected: false,
    description: "Mall",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
}, {
    text: "Shopping Plaza",
    value: 12,
    selected: false,
    description: "Shopping Plaza",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
}];
```

The code to change the data for the second drop-down box is as follows:

```
$('#inames').ddslick({
    data: categoryData,
    width: 300,
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select a place",
    onSelected: function (data) {
        updateDropDown(data.selectedData.value);
    }
});
$("#ddslicks").ddslick({width: 300,
        imagePosition: "left",
                        selectText: "Select"});

function updateDropDown(value) {
    var newData;
    if (value == 1) {
        newData = utilitiesData;
    } else {
        newData = generalData;
    }
    $('#ddslicks').ddslick("destroy");
    $("#ddslicks").empty();
    $("#ddslicks").ddslick({
        data: newData,
        width: 300,
        imagePosition: "left",
        selectText: "Select"
    });
}
```

Most likely, you could replace the update statement with something different - maybe a function in the chained.js?  It works this way though.

**UPDATE (based on comments below):**

**To enable scrolling for a stylized 'Text Box' (as requested below in the comments)**

When you use a JavaScript plug-in to stylize a drop down, it often 'emulates' a select box and isn't really using the HTML select element.  This means the options you put on the select element in your code often is not captured in the rendered code, unless it is something built into the plug-in.  This is the case with the plug-in ddslick.

Below is the rendered code for the drop down box:

```
    <div id="inames" class="dd-container" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="dd-select" style="width: 300px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden"> <a class="dd-selected">Select a place</a>
 <span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span> 
    </div>
    <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 300px;">
        <li> <a class="dd-option">
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="1">
                <label class="dd-option-text">Utilities</label > 
                <small class = "dd-option-description dd-desc"> Utilities</small>
            </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a class="dd-option">
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="2">
                <label class="dd-option-text">Emergency Services</label > 
                    <small class = "dd-option-description dd-desc" > Emergency Services </small>
            </a> 
        </li>
        <li>
<a class="dd-option">
<input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="3">
    <label class="dd-option-text">General</label > < small class = "dd-option-description dd-desc" > General </mall>
</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="ddslicks" class="dd-container" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="dd-select" style="width: 300px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden">
<a class="dd-selected">Select</a > <span class = "dd-pointer dd-pointer-down" > </span>

    </div>
    <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 300px;"></ul>
</div>
```

If you look at the code, you'll see that there aren't any select elements listed.  Instead, the 'select box' is composed of a div, with an unordered list (with a link surrounding the list items) embedded in it.

The element surrounding the 'drop down options' is `dd-options`.  If you want to add scrolling to an unordered list, what do you do?  You add a max-height to the CSS.  Therefore, to make this work properly, add a CSS style rule to your custom stylesheet.

```
.dd-options {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Change the `max-height` value to whatever you want.  Now you have a scrolling, stylized drop-down box!

See the fiddle here for a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/Uw9kL/11/

Comment: please can you give me suggestion or help for this 3 issues... images drop down box scroll bar and when i select image get alert image name and also is possible images drop down box with out names i.e only images.

Comment: I'll try to look at it later tonight or sometime tomorrow.  glad the code helped!  In the meantime, I'm guessing that you can just leave out the name / description in your data if you just want the image.  Also, you can add in the alert in the update method.

Comment: Is this more along the lines of what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/Uw9kL/8/ I'm not sure what you mean about the scroll bar though

Comment: thanks again.. in application am using jquery.nicescroll.js for scroll bar. this given code image drop down used in pop up window so when i used more number of images then pop up body disturbed,when i click drop down then it shows 4/5 images then remain when i scrolling ...am using scroll bar is e.x. $("body").niceScroll();

Comment: please look out this [(http://jsfiddle.net/thiru/Uw9kL/10/ i added more images for general drop down but did not get scrolling in images drop box.